# Can I make my background service not stop or pause in kotlin? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, kotlin, service, background

I am making a stopwatch app and would like my stopwatch to continue after 1 minute of the app being closed or the phone being turned off. I was wondering if there was any way for me to make my timer service continue working after the the app is paused. In the background service I am currently using the timer function stop exactly 1 minute after the app is closed. I have been searching the internet for solutions which have pointed me towards foreground services but I am very inexperienced and cannot figure out how to make them work.

Here is my timer service (I got this from [Code With Cal](https://www.youtube.com/c/CodeWithCal) on youtube)

```
class TimerService : Service() {
override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? = null

private val timer = Timer()

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    val time = intent.getDoubleExtra(TIME_EXTRA, 0.0)
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimeTask(time), 0, 1000)
    return START_NOT_STICKY
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    timer.cancel()
    super.onDestroy()
}

private inner class TimeTask(private var time: Double) : TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {
        val intent = Intent(TIMER_UPDATED)
        time++
        intent.putExtra(TIME_EXTRA, time)
        sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
}

companion object {
    const val TIMER_UPDATED = "timerUpdated"
    const val TIME_EXTRA = "timeExtra"
}
```

Can I make this into a service that continues on when the app is closed? Thank you so much (Note: This is my first app and I am very inexperienced. If there is any more code you need, please tell me, thanks!)

Comment: Nope, you can't do that, but you don't really need/want to, anyway. All you really need to know whenever your app is setting up the stopwatch is the starting time of the current timing session, and the time it is right now. If you save that starting time somewhere persistent – e.g., in `SharedPreferences` – then you just need to retrieve that value and do some simple arithmetic to get the stopwatch re-set correctly. Make sense?

Comment: That is so smart! I will try my best to do this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike M. Answered in the comments:
"Nope, you can't do that, but you don't really need/want to, anyway. All you really need to know whenever your app is setting up the stopwatch is the starting time of the current timing session, and the time it is right now. If you save that starting time somewhere persistent – e.g., in SharedPreferences – then you just need to retrieve that value and do some simple arithmetic to get the stopwatch re-set correctly."

-Thanks so much (-Casper)